# How to use Type calculated in Scala Macro in a reify clause?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I've been working with Scala Macros and have the following code in the macro:

```
    val fieldMemberType = fieldMember.typeSignatureIn(objectType) match {
      case NullaryMethodType(tpe)   => tpe
      case _                      => doesntCompile(s"$propertyName isn't a field, it must be another thing")
    }

    reify{
      new TypeBuilder() {
        type fieldType = fieldMemberType.type
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I've managed to get a `c.universe.Type fieldMemberType`. This represents the type of certain field in the object. Once I get that, I want to create a new `TypeBuilder` object in the reify. `TypeBuilder` is an abstract class with an abstract parameter. This abstract parameter is `fieldType`. I want this `fieldType` to be the type that I've found before.

Running the code shown here returns me a `fieldMemberType not found`. Is there any way that I can get the `fieldMemberType` to work inside the reify clause?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that the code you pass to `reify` is essentially going to be placed verbatim at the point where the macro is being expanded, and `fieldMemberType` isn't going to mean anything there.

In some cases you can use `splice` to sneak an expression that you have at macro-expansion time into the code you're reifying. For example, if we were trying to create an instance of this trait:

```
trait Foo { def i: Int }
```

And had this variable at macro-expansion time:

```
val myInt = 10
```

We could write the following:

```
reify { new Foo { def i = c.literal(myInt).splice } }
```

That's not going to work here, which means you're going to have to forget about nice little `reify` and write out the AST by hand. You'll find this happens a lot, unfortunately. My standard approach is to start a new REPL and type something like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait TypeBuilder { type fieldType }

showRaw(reify(new TypeBuilder { type fieldType = String }))
```

This will spit out several lines of AST, which you can then cut and paste into your macro definition as a starting point. Then you fiddle with it, replacing things like this:

```
Ident(TypeBuilder)
```

With this:

```
Ident(newTypeName("TypeBuilder"))
```

And `FINAL` with `Flag.FINAL`, and so on. I wish the `toString` methods for the AST types corresponded more exactly to the code it takes to build them, but you'll pretty quickly get a sense of what you need to change. You'll end up with something like this:

```
c.Expr(
  Block(
    ClassDef(
      Modifiers(Flag.FINAL),
      anon,
      Nil,
      Template(
        Ident(newTypeName("TypeBuilder")) :: Nil,
        emptyValDef,
        List(
          constructor(c),
          TypeDef(
            Modifiers(),
            newTypeName("fieldType"),
            Nil,
            TypeTree(fieldMemberType)
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    Apply(Select(New(Ident(anon)), nme.CONSTRUCTOR), Nil)
  )
)
```

Where `anon` is a type name you've created in advance for your anonymous class, and `constructor` is a convenience method I use to make this kind of thing a little less hideous (you can find its definition at the end of [this complete working example](https://gist.github.com/4249936)).

Now if we wrap this expression up in something like [this](https://gist.github.com/4249936), we can write the following:

```
scala> TypeMemberExample.builderWithType[String]
res0: TypeBuilder{type fieldType = String} = $1$$1@fb3f1f3
```

So it works. We've taken a `c.universe.Type` (which I get here from the `WeakTypeTag` of the type parameter on `builderWithType`, but it will work in exactly the same way with any old `Type`) and used it to define the type member of our `TypeBuilder` trait.

Comment: Just one question, how does the "newTypeName" finds the Type? I mean how does it know in which package this is?

Comment: Thanks! And `newTypeName` doesn't hunt down the type itself—it just copies the string you give it into the code that the macro is generating, which will then be type-checked by the compiler as usual. If you need to specify the package you can write e.g. `Select(Ident("package"), newTypeName("MyClass"))`.

Comment: You can use `-Yreify-copypaste` and/or `showRaw` to obtain the code that builds the snippets of code you're interested in.

Comment: One comment about this, the typeDef doesn't work if you have a Type with a Generic type on IT. So, in this case, if your fieldMemberType was a Option[String] this would have thrown an exception. The right way to do this is using a TypeTree TypeTree(fieldMemberType).

Answer (score 7):

There is a simpler approach than tree writing for your use case. Indeed I use it all the time to keep trees at bay, as it can be really difficult to program with trees. I prefer to compute types and use reify to generate the trees. This makes much more robust and "hygienic" macros and less compile time errors. IMO using trees must be a last resort, only for a few cases, such as tree transforms or generic programming for a family of types such as tuples.

The tip here is to define a function taking as type parameters, the types you want to use in the reify body, with a context bound on a WeakTypeTag. Then you call this function by passing explicitly the WeakTypeTags you can build from universe Types thanks to the context WeakTypeTag method.

So in your case, that would give the following.

```
  val fieldMemberType: Type = fieldMember.typeSignatureIn(objectType) match {
      case NullaryMethodType(tpe)   => tpe
      case _                      => doesntCompile(s"$propertyName isn't a field, it must be            another thing")
  }

  def genRes[T: WeakTypeTag] = reify{
    new TypeBuilder() {
      type fieldType = T
    }
  }

  genRes(c.WeakTypeTag(fieldMemberType))
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach. Thanks

Comment: +1 (and I should have noticed that this approach works here), but in my experience there are lots of cases (maybe most) where working with the trees directly is unavoidable—in particular any time you need to refer to (or create) methods or classes by their names as strings. For example, [here](https://github.com/travisbrown/rillit), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13335741/334519), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13447439/334519) etc.